# Where did comment-edited indicator go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, comments

I just noticed that we can't distinguish if a comment was edited or not anymore. There is no indicator. Why this happened? I can now include someone else's comment to my earlier one and making his viewpoints a copy.

Comment: This comment was edited 9 times. (Who knows?!) This question seems to be [raised on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312829/comments-no-longer-indicate-whether-or-not-theyve-been-edited) but got no valid comment.

Comment: Raised on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312829/comments-no-longer-indicate-whether-or-not-theyve-been-edited

Comment: May have impeded the always-presence of the flag and upvote buttons

Comment: I feel bad. I had never noticed that that indicator existed. :(

Comment: an update to the [ReduceClutter](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) userscript fixes this issue in the meantime

Comment: @yivi don't feel bad... I have *never* seen this before... and I'd very much like for it to go away, again.  I tend to make trivial edits to my comments because I detest leaving a typo behind... and these are ugly, distracting, and largely pointless.  I came over to meta exactly because I was hoping to find evidence that this new thing was a horrible idea that was immediately regretted and would be removed promptly.  No luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has been fixed and will go live in the next build. Thanks for reporting!

Answer (score 9):

The information exists in HTML markup but seems CSS has some problems:

```html
<a href="/users/1020526/revo" title="28,628 reputation" class="comment-user owner">revo</a>
<span class="comment-date" dir="ltr"><a class="comment-link" href="#comment611641_371284"><span title="2018-07-19 10:54:53Z" class="relativetime-clean">3 hours ago</span></a></span>
<span class="edited-yes" title="this comment was edited 12 times"></span>
```